# Testing selector presence in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

Does anyone know how I can go about testing this in Jasmine?

```
function gameWon() {
  $('#final_message_cpu').html('You WON!!!')
  $('.computer_selection').css('display', 'block');
  $('#show_after_starting').remove();
  $('#hide_after_starting').css('display', 'inline')
  $('#hide_after_starting').click(function() {
    location.reload();
 })
}
```

Is there a way I can just test to see if $('#show_after_starting') has been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
expect($('#show_after_starting').length).toBe(0);
```